# Listing Page pullling in latest article for every article

Tags: listing

I have created a listing page and each time a new entry is created the information is pulled in correctly in the loop. Although when I click on the link for a specific blog article it always displays the latest articles info, regardless of what blog article I click. The URL is always correct, although the content that is being displayed is wrong. You can see here for yourself here: http://www.neilmct.com/updates

Can anyone help me please? I'm having a melt down here.

Listing Page:

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="updates" dynamic="no" limit="5" dynamic="off" status="open" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
                <div class="nine columns">
                        <h3>
                            {title}
                        </h3>
                        <img src="{updates_image}" alt="{title}" width="300" height="200" 
                        class="updates-bleep">
                        {exp:eehive_hacksaw chars="540" append="…" allow=""}
                            <p class="article-excerpt" style="color: #000; display: inline">{updates_excerpt}</p>
                        {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
                        <a href="{page_url}" style="display: block">
                            <button> READ MORE 
                                <img src="/assets/images/button-white.png" style="float:right"/>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </article>
                </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Detail Page:

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="updates" dynamic="no" limit="1" dynamic="off" status="open" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
                <div class="nine columns">
                    <article class="box-services-updates alpha">
                        <h3>
                            {title}
                        </h3>
                        <img src="{updates_image}" alt="{title}">
                            <p class="article-article">{updates_article}
                            </p>
                    </article>
                    <a class="updates-back" href="/updates"> &laquo; Back </a>
                </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: show us your channel entries tags, please.

Comment: Send me your email address and i will email u two screen shots of the listing and detail page if u dont mind. Stack exchange wont let me upload an image

Comment: Update your answer and add the code of the exp:channel:entries, please.

Comment: Robson i have updated my posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your detail page, assuming the content is triggered off the URL?

If so, you need to have dynamic="yes" to affect the channel entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="updates" dynamic="yes" limit="1" status="open" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
```

Note too that you have both dynamic="off" and dynamic="no" in there. On your detail page, try removing both of those, and replace with dynamic="yes"

Comment: cheers Pal :).......

Comment: NOTE: dynamic="yes" is enabled on the channel:entries tag by default so no need to specifically add it... you just need to remove dynamic="no" and things will work as expected.